# Using List Comprehension with Pandas Series and Dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension, series

I have written the below code that accepts a pandas series (dataframe column) of strings and a dictionary of terms to replace in the strings.

```
def phrase_replace(repl_dict, str_series):
    for k,v in repl_dict.items():
         str_series = str_series.str.replace(k,v)
    return str_series
```

It works correctly, but it seems like I should be able to use some kind of list comprehension instead of the for loop. 
I don't want to use `str_series = []` or `{}` because I don't want a list or a dictionary returned, but a `pandas.core.series.Series`

Likewise, if I want to use the function on every column in a dataframe:

```
for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = phrase_replace(repl_dict, df[column])
```

There must be a list comprehension method to do this?

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry and jezrael were both correct. I can replace my function with df.replace and apply to all columns using pd.concat(). Thankyou both

Comment: I don't understand the problem with your current `for` loop method. If anything, it's likely to be more efficient, readable and adaptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but then need [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for `DataFrame` because get `list of Series`:

```
df = pd.concat([phrase_replace(repl_dict, df[column]) for column in df.columns], axis=1)
```

But maybe need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by dictionary:

```
df = df.replace(repl_dict)
```

Comment: Ok, yes, pd.concat will work for using it on all columns. Thankyou both.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'words':['apple','banana','orange']})
repl_dict = {'an':'foo', 'pp':'zz'}
df.replace({'words':repl_dict}, inplace=True, regex=True)

df
Out[263]:
      words
0     azzle
1  bfoofooa
2   orfooge
```

If you want to apply to all columns:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key1':['apple', 'banana', 'orange'], 'key2':['banana', 'apple', 'pineapple']})

df2
Out[13]:
     key1       key2
0   apple     banana
1  banana      apple
2  orange  pineapple

df2.replace(repl_dict,inplace=True, regex=True)

df2
Out[15]:
       key1       key2
0     azzle   bfoofooa
1  bfoofooa      azzle
2   orfooge  pineazzle
```

The whole point of pandas is to not use for loops... it's optimized to use the built in methods for dataframes and series...

Comment: Thankyou, this would work for the replace function, but I run into the same problem when I want to apply it to all columns of the dataframe - needing a for loop? Here is your example adjusted: `df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'key1':'apple banana orange', 'key2':'banana apple pineapple'}])
repl_dict = {'an':'foo', 'pp':'zz'} df2.replace({'key1':repl_dict}, inplace=True, regex=True)'

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html